# I created a button several buttons using code. I need to change their background color when clicked

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a code to create several buttons based on user input (rows and columns.) I would like to change the background color (individually) for each of them when clicked.

[This is the code that creates buttons based on user input(rows and columns.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgA7u.png)

[This is the handler for the click event where I put the code. There is a boolean variable to control the background color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfsuf.png)

I tried using If/Select Case statements; however, for some reason it will never make it past the first time, meaning it will not switch back to initial background color when clicked again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AoOd.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).. Also, your OnClick code has a clear logic error - you set the state to false at the top of the procedure, and then use that state in the case statement. If you've set the state to False every time, the state will always be False when it reaches the Case. You should learn to read your code, or at least learn to use the debugger to step through it so you can spot silly mistakes like this one.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That would actually get the outcome I was trying to achieve. I'm still learning to code; therefore, that silly mistake happened.

Comment: Might find some use in using a check control instead of a button control.  These can be styled to look like buttons and have a pressed state built in

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should make them toggle between Blue and Green:

```
Friend Sub xButton_Click(sender As Object, e as EventArgs)
    Dim Btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    If Btn.BackColor = Color.Blue Then
        Btn.BackColor = Color.Green
    Else
        Btn.BackColor = Color.Blue
    End IF
End Sub
```